# I'm unable to cast TargetDataLine to a line

Tags: java, audio

The program below i have works by recording from microphone for 5 sec and then it would automatically replay it. However i'm getting an error from casting TargetDataLine to Audio.getLine(). Any help is very appriciated!

```
public class Audio3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
    
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);
    
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    final SourceDataLine sourceLine = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    sourceLine.open();
    
    info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    final TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    targetLine.open();
    
    final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    
    Thread sourceThread = new Thread() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sourceLine.start();
            
            while(true) {
                //out.size() also works fine
                sourceLine.write(out.toByteArray(), 0, out.toByteArray().length);
            }
        }
    };
    
    
    Thread targetThread = new Thread() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            targetLine.start();
            byte[] data = new byte[targetLine.getBufferSize() / 5];
            int readBytes;
            
            while(true) {
                readBytes = targetLine.read(data, 0, data.length);
                out.write(data, 0, readBytes);
            }
        }
    };

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `SourceDataLine.class` to `TargetDataLine.class`:

```java
    info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format); // changed
    final TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    targetLine.open();
```